Is there a more traditional, colloquial name for the Feast of the Circumcision of Christ?
Several major Christian holidays have a more colloquial (and usually shorter) name along with their more 'official' name, e.g., Candlemas/Feast of the Presentation of Christ; Johnsmas/Nativity of St John the Baptist; Michaelmas/Feast of St Michael and All Angels. Is there a similar colloquial short name for the Feast of the Circumcision of Christ? And if there isn't, is this indicative of the holiday never having been a big cultural holiday? If people used to be in the habit of referring to this day in everyday speech, its full name would seem to have been rather a mouthful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feast_of_the_Circumcision_of_Christ  "In Western Christianity, the Feast of the Naming and Circumcision of Jesus Christ marks the eighth day (octave day) of Christmastide."

I’m voting to close this question because it lacks any sign of research, and were suitable research to prove unhelpful, would be a better fit on Christianity.SE. Christian jargon is usually far more arcane than standard usages. I'd guess that fewer than 50% of seasoned Anglophones are familiar with any of the terms you give as examples, other than Michaelmas.

I suspect that the most colloquial name that the most people would recognize is "New Year's Day"...
